# Kendo DataSource .slice and template issues

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I've been trying to solve this for a couple of days but without any success.
I have a scrollview set with a datasource that gets from the server.

At first it kept crashing after the successful request in the following line in jQuery `that._pristineData = data.slice(0);` because `data` was an object and not an array.

After some searching around I found an answer that said to return the response of the schema in square brackets so it's basically an array.

This did fix the issue, however now it's crashing elsewhere, so maybe it's not the correct approach to fix the problem wholly.

I am getting the following error now : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined has no properties` at VM and viewing the code that caused the error gives me this :

```
(function(data
/**/) {
var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){o='<div><p>Title: '+e( data.title )+'</p><p>Street: '+e( data.street )+'</p></div>';}return o;
})
```

**Is there something wrong with my template?
Could it be that returning the response as an array causes this issue?
How can I fix this?**

`scrollview`

```
<div>
    <kendo-mobile-scroll-view id="scroll" k-data-source="data" k-template="template" >
    </kendo-mobile-scroll-view>
</div>
```

`datasource`

```
$scope.data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: $scope.link,
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function(data) {
            return [data];
        }
    }
});
```

`template`

```
$scope.template = "<div><p>Title: #: data.title #</p><p>Street: #: data.street #</p></div>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely something wrong in response. I have tried example similar to yours and all works fine. Look at demo [Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oXajA).

Response from server must look like:

```
[{"title":"title1","street":"street1"},{"title":"title2","street":"street2"}]
```